# Why can't my CNN learn?

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to deep learning. And I just implemented a CNN with Tensorflow and was trying it on CIFAR-10 (An object recognition benchmark, where images are in **10 different classes**).

During the process of training, the training loss decreased really fast at the beginning(from 100000 to 3), but then it always stuck at around **2.30**(which is approximately log(1/10)). Since I use cross-entropy as loss function, a loss of 2.30 means my model has an accuracy around 10% ---- exactly the same as guessing randomly(I have checked the actual output of model, really almost all around 10% for each class).

I tried to increase the size of model so as to try whether it is because my model is not "strong" enough to overfit. But it turns out that the training loss would always stop decreasing at around 2.30 no matter how I increase or decrease the model size.

I am quite confident that I implemented it correctly, since my model worked for easier task such as MNIST(handwritten digit recognition). So I really wonder what the problem might be. Thanks a lot.
[image]

conv1: convolution layer with relu

pooling1: max pooling layer

fc1: fully-connected layer with relu

output: fully-connected layer with softmax

**CODE:**

```
nn = NeuralNetwork(optimizer=Adam(0.001), log_dir='logs')
nn.add(Input('input', [32, 32, 3], ))
nn.add(Convolution2D(name='conv1', filter_height=3, filter_width=3, 
                     n_output_channels=256, activation_fn='relu'))
nn.add(Pooling2D('pooling1', mode='max', pool_shape=(3, 3), padding='SAME'))
nn.add(Convolution2D(name='conv2', filter_height=3, filter_width=3, 
                     n_output_channels=128, activation_fn='relu'))
nn.add(Pooling2D('pooling2', mode='max', pool_shape=(3, 3), padding='SAME'))
nn.add(FullyConnected('fc1', 384, activation_fn='relu',
                      weight_init=truncated_normal(), bias_init=constant(0.1)))
nn.add(FullyConnected('fc2', 192, activation_fn='relu', 
                      weight_init=truncated_normal(), bias_init=constant(0.1)))
nn.add(Output(loss_fn='sparse_softmax_cross_entropy', output_fn='softmax',
              name='output', target_shape=[], target_dtype=tf.int64, 
              output_shape=10))
nn.build()
```

**EDIT:**

As I have mentioned. I tried to increase the complexity of my model by adding more layers and almost tried the one on tutorial, except that I do not have norm layers(conv1, pooling1, conv2, pooling2, fc1, fc2, softmax) and preprocessiong like whitening etc. for simplicity, which I think might not compromise my performance as serious as from 86% to 10%.

**Another clue that I think might help is that I found the output of layer `fc1` is extremely sparse(almost 99% elements are zeros). Since I use ReLU as activation function, it means the units in fc1 are mostly dead. I there any thing I can do with it?**

Comment: Have you checked your labels twice, maybe while shuffling the data something goes wrong?

Comment: MNIST had simpler features so one conv layer was enough, 
to start learning on a dataset of real images like CIFAR-10 you would need to add atleast another conv-layer.  i.e conv2 and pool2.

follow this example : 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py

Comment: Yes, but I have also tried it with two conv layers and 2 pooling layers. Still stuck at around 2.3

Comment: Have you done much hyperparameter optimization with the more complex models?  Maybe if you post a minimal version of your code, it will help.  I can barely read the tensor shapes in your graph, but it looks like it's [?, 32, 32, 3] => CONV1/POOL1 => [?, 16, 16, 128] => CONV2/POOL2 => [?, 8, 8, 64].  If I read that correctly, that's unlikely to work well.  The "width" of the network is very wide after the first convolution, and then it narrows down sharply, with the second convolution throwing away *many* features.  [?, 32, 32, 3] => [?, 16, 16, 64] => [?, 8, 8, 128] would be better.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code.  I'm not sure exactly what it does - looks like it's using some non-standard functions (maybe infrastructure that you've created?)  I'd recommend using 5x5 kernels.  (3x3 kernels can work - VGGNet is a good example, but of course that's a *much* deeper network architecture.)  And per my previous comment, consider avoiding sharp changes in the width of the network.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, I will try to make it less sharp. And yes, that is a toy infrastructure I implemented for exercise, https://github.com/lifuhuang/legonet. Hope it's not because of bugs I made. Really appreciate any suggestions or pull requests :)

Comment: @LifuHuang I am facing a similar problem with my Tensorflow-gpu installation, wherein CNNs won't learn. Perceptrons and RNNs work fine for me. Also, I tried using the CPU version and the same network works perfectly, pointing that there is nothing wrong with the code. I have asked a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65475010/why-is-tensorflow-official-cnn-example-stuck-at-10-percent-accuracy-random-pr. Please do reply if you find a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible that you're just seriously underestimating the architecture required to achieve reasonable results on this task.  The model you described (input->conv1->pooling1->fc1->output) may be adequate for MNIST, but that doesn't mean that it can achieve better than random results on an image classification task involving real color images.

The reality is that you'd need to provide the actual code for people to provide more concrete recommendations, but based on the model you've described I would at least recommend looking at some other models that can solve this problem.  For example, Tensorflow comes with an [example CNN](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html) that can achieve ~86% accuracy on CIFAR-10, but this model is more complex.  And even with the additional convolutional and fully-connected layers, normalization, and input pre-processing (whitening, data augmentation, etc.), and tuned hyperparameters, it still takes several hours of training on a powerful GPU to obtain good results.

Anyway, long story short, I think you should review the example model to get a feel for the kind of architecture that's needed.  It's easy to underestimate how much more complex it is to identify objects in random color images vs. black and white sets of numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I have mentioned. I tried to increase the complexity of my model by adding more layers and **almost** tried the one on tutorial, except that I do not have norm layers(conv1, pooling1, conv2, pooling2, fc1, fc2, softmax) and preprocessiong like whitening etc. for simplicity, which I think might not compromise my performance as serious as from 86% to 10%, might it?

Comment: What hyperparameter optimization did you try with the more complex models?  Even minor differences in the architecture of the NN can require substantial hyperparameter optimization in order to achieve better than random accuracy.

Comment: Hi, @Aenimated, I have posted my code. BTW, it's slightly different from the version at beginning, since I made it more complex, but still not much progress.