# Why is Tensorflow Official CNN example stuck at 10 percent accuracy (= random prediction) on my machine?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.x

I am running the CNN example from Tensorflow Official website - (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn)
I have run the notebook as it is without any modifications whatsoever.

My accuracy (training accuracy) is stuck at 10%.
I tried to overfit by only using the first 10 (image, label) pairs, but the result is still the same. The network just does not learn.

Here is my model.summary() -

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 30, 30, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 15, 15, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 13, 13, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 6, 6, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 4, 4, 64)          36928     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                65600     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                650       
=================================================================
Total params: 122,570
Trainable params: 122,570
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Here is my compile and fit code:-

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10, 
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

The model training logs:-

```
Epoch 1/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 14s 9ms/step - loss: 2.3072 - accuracy: 0.0993 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_accuracy: 0.0994
Epoch 2/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3028 - accuracy: 0.0996 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_accuracy: 0.1001
Epoch 3/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3029 - accuracy: 0.0998 - val_loss: 2.3027 - val_accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 4/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3038 - accuracy: 0.0986 - val_loss: 2.3054 - val_accuracy: 0.1007
Epoch 5/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3031 - accuracy: 0.0988 - val_loss: 2.3026 - val_accuracy: 0.0999
Epoch 6/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3031 - accuracy: 0.0985 - val_loss: 2.3159 - val_accuracy: 0.0999
Epoch 7/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3221 - accuracy: 0.0995 - val_loss: 2.9215 - val_accuracy: 0.1003
Epoch 8/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3035 - accuracy: 0.0973 - val_loss: 2.3270 - val_accuracy: 0.1001
Epoch 9/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3028 - accuracy: 0.0999 - val_loss: 2.3399 - val_accuracy: 0.0984
Epoch 10/10
1563/1563 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 2.3054 - accuracy: 0.1001 - val_loss: 2.3116 - val_accuracy: 0.1002
```

I have checked the plotted data and it is not random. The labels are correct and there is no issue with the data that I can see.

I am running this code on Tensorflow 2.2 on an Nvidia RTX 3060 Ti

```
__CUDA Information__
CUDA Device Initialized                       : True
CUDA Driver Version                           : 11010
CUDA Detect Output:
Found 1 CUDA devices

cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.1_0
```

Please help.

Comment: what are your activation functions for each dense layer?

Comment: So it's the very same code yeah? You divided by 255?

Comment: @Proko I am using 'Relu' activation function for each layer, except for the last layer. I am not using any activation function for the last layer. This works because I use the param 'from_logits=True' in the loss function calculation.

Comment: @GaussianPrior I downloaded the notebook and executed it. So, it's exactly the same. And to answer your question - I am dividing by 255.0

Comment: Very weird. I just run it on colab and it works as it should. Probably some sort of disagreement between versions? (like Tensorflow vers) Other than that the only reason I could think of that stops the network from training properly is a bad weight initialization, but I doubt that would occur every time you run the model. Sorry, I cannot think of anything else :/

Comment: I tried a couple more convolution examples .. and it is always the case that the network does not train. I tried running a Feedforward net and a RNN. They work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is just because you are using less data with little bigger model comparatively to data. Either you need to use `more data` or define the model with `less layers` to avoid such issue.

I tried replicating this issue in the same `TensorFlow version==2.2.0`.

if you are using 10 images, 10 labels (small dataset), better use one convolution layer with:

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
```

And the `model.summary()`

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 30, 30, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 15, 15, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 7200)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                460864    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                650       
=================================================================
Total params: 462,410
Trainable params: 462,410
Non-trainable params: 0
```

and the Model training logs will be:(Accuracy:90%)

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 347ms/step - loss: 2.3649 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 2.4008 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 75ms/step - loss: 2.0693 - accuracy: 0.2000 - val_loss: 2.4810 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 53ms/step - loss: 1.9101 - accuracy: 0.2000 - val_loss: 2.5218 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 64ms/step - loss: 1.7163 - accuracy: 0.4000 - val_loss: 2.5354 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 60ms/step - loss: 1.5290 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 2.5635 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 59ms/step - loss: 1.3485 - accuracy: 0.9000 - val_loss: 2.6416 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 63ms/step - loss: 1.1629 - accuracy: 0.9000 - val_loss: 2.7497 - val_accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 8/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 61ms/step - loss: 0.9642 - accuracy: 0.9000 - val_loss: 2.8680 - val_accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 9/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 58ms/step - loss: 0.8041 - accuracy: 0.9000 - val_loss: 2.9326 - val_accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 10/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 69ms/step - loss: 0.6698 - accuracy: 0.9000 - val_loss: 2.9153 - val_accuracy: 0.1000
```